# Error "No speakable text present" although having android:hint

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Even though I already have the android:hint field but still got the error message "No speakable text present. This item may not have a label readable by screen readers."

[image]
[image]

I want to a few solutions for this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The problem indicates that there is no text to play when the user uses the wizard, you need to add a description of the content so that the user can learn information about the view.

In addition to adding

```
android:hint="@string/password"
```

Also add your "Content description":

```
android:contentDescription="@string/view_description"
```